# Break HTML tooltip message using line breaks

Tags: javascript, html, angular, tooltip

I'm trying to break my custom HTML tooltip that I used inside the button **Hover Button**.
I tried using different approach(ie., /n, &#013) in typescript as it's a custom tooltip to add a line break and nothing seem to work.

Below is the tooltip data that I'm using and the fiddle associated with the same:

```
 tooltipData="Helo,Angular 2" + "&#013" + "This button is used to test hover message" + "/n" + "This message should come at the last"
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mailmrmanoj/mjuroa62/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong slash - new line should be \n not /n:

```
tooltipData="Helo,Angular 2" + "&#013" + "This button is used to test hover message" + "\n" + "This message should come at the last"
```

Comment: Thanks @jack. I updated the fiddle and wanted to use &nbsp; as space and it dosen't seem to work .Please help

Comment: Well that's different, but does my fix work for you?

Comment: Thanks jack.Can you please comment on this issue that I'm facing https://github.com/predixdesignsystem/px-tooltip/issues/36 ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this -

```html
<div title="Helo,Angular 2&#013;&#010;This button is used to test hover message&#009;This message should come at the last">Hover Me</div>
```

Here I used -

```
&#010; - for New line
```

I Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Update your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mailmrmanoj/mjuroa62/1/) to use `\n` rather than `/n`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this code will work in all browser !!i used 
 for new line in chrome and safari and ul li for IE

```
function genarateMultiLIneCode(){
var =values["a","b","c"];
const liStart = '<li>';
      const liEnd = '</li>';
      const bullet = '&#8226; ';     
      var mergedString = ' ';
      const unOrderListStart='<ul>'
      const unOrderListEnd='</ul>'
      const fakeNewline = '&#013;&#010;';
      for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
           mergedString += liStart + bullet + values[i] + liEnd + fakeNewline;
      }
      const tempElement = document.createElement("div");
      tempElement.innerHTML = unOrderListStart + mergedString + unOrderListEnd;    
      return tempElement.innerText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var =values["RAHUL","BIKASH","RAMAN"];
const liStart = '<li>';
      const liEnd = '</li>';
      const bullet = '&#8226; ';     
      var mergedString = ' ';
      const unOrderListStart='<ul>'
      const unOrderListEnd='</ul>'
      const fakeNewline = '&#013;&#010;';
      for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
           mergedString += liStart + bullet + values[i] + liEnd + fakeNewline;
      }
      const tempElement = document.createElement("div");
      tempElement.innerHTML = unOrderListStart + mergedString + unOrderListEnd;
```

then use **tempElement.innerText**